# CSS: Wrap text AND break word if necessary

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break

How can I set up a div such that it will wrap text AND will also break word if necessary?  Examples below, with the dots showing the width of the div ("zzzzzzz..." is all one word).

....................................
Hello these are
words

....................................
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzz

Answer (score 7):

You can use css `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 50px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">This is a mormal div wrapping and breaking words</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

and if you want a word to be separated at a certain position when it's too long for the container, you can use the `&shy;` entity (soft hyphen). So the HTML

```
singledoubletriple&shy;quadruplequintupleburger
```

will remain

```
singledoubletriplequadruplequintupleburger
```

on the screen when it fits in one line, but become

```
singledoubletriple-
quadruplequintupleburger
```

if the line is shorter

Comment: That's neat, did not know about this.