# Break text by word, break anyways if no space

Tags: css

I am trying to break a text by word if possible, and if not - break anyways so the layout isn't dying. This works by default in google chrome and wraps properly, but it doesn't work in firefox.

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.a>div {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>

    achrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachri

  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prswjktc/12/

The problem can be solved by adding `max-width: 100%;` in the case in the fiddle but I am looking for alternative solutions. (I can't remove the inner div either).

Comment: @jackjop What? Sure the browsers knows what words are and that they are seperated by spaces. I want a string like `this is a sentence` to be breaked on space and a string like `qwzueqweqweNO_SPACES_HERE` to be forcefully breaked when needed.

Comment: okay my mistake. didn't understand what you mean

Comment: in this case you need to give the inner space a width of `100%` or `width: inherit;` because the inner div doesn't have any width limit. to break the word the dom has to provide a specific width and unfortunately firefox has this problem so you need to add width

Answer (score 4):

#### Here we go :-)

1. Put your words (or terms) into `<span>`s.
2. set to

   - `display: inline-block` (so they get all the width they need)
   - `max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden` (so, yes, there's a chop-off, if column exceed)
   - `overflow-wrap: break-word` (so he breaks *if* there's a chop-off
   - legacy backup (think `-moz-whatever`): `word-wrap: break-word`

code:

```
span
  display: inline-block
  max-width: 100%
  overflow-wrap: break-word
  word-wrap: break-word
```

### [full Codepen](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/KKwgdNm?editors=1100)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS3 property `overflow-wrap`, which may be what you're looking for. Read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap), including about browser support, but the gist is that "In contrast to `word-break`, `overflow-wrap` will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing."

Note also that the width of 200px you have is not on the div that contains the long text but on the .a parent div, and that the div with the long text has `display: inline-block`, so currently its width will be determined by its content and it will spill out of the fixed-width .a parent div. To fix this, either give the inner div (`.a > div`) an explicit width (could be 200px, or 100%, or whatever your layout actually requires), or make the inner div display as a block by removing `display: inline-block` and/or setting `display: block` explicitly.

Here's a working snippet, in which I've left .a > div as an inline-block, and created another div .b where .b > div is a block:

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.a>div {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.b {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}

.b>div {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>

    achrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachri

  </div>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <div>

    achrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachri

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That sounds really good but for whatever reason its not working for my production code. I'll look into it more and let you know if it worked. thanks. My reproduction code (fiddle) is sadly flawed I guess..

Comment: @Xatenev based on chatting with you about your production code and its container width problems, I just wanted to share one more possibility I thought of, which could be an adequate short-term fix if not a long-term solution. You could apply a max-width of 100vw on the child element that you want to wrap the long content of, so that at the very least it will wrap to within the width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Add `word-break:break-all;` to the child selector (`.a > div`)

https://jsfiddle.net/f4bdx7z9/1/

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:normal;
  word-break:break-word;
}

.a > div {
  text-align:left;
  display:inline-block;
  word-break:break-all;

}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<div>

achrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachriachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichtchrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachrichteinenachri

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is no possible solution to my problem. I want to break **by word** if possible and if not **by all**. Your solution would break by all in every case. See http://jsfiddle.net/prswjktc/39/

Comment: Then you might want to try the solution I proposed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36160763/5641669

Comment: that is really nice to know thanks. But I don't think it helps me in this case... I don't know at what position the text breaks (like.. looking at the page in different resolutions for example the element this is in becomes smaller/bigger thus the text wraps at a different position)

Comment: Well, you can use that `&shy` tag several times in  a word, and it will break at the latest possible position automatically.

Comment: thats a really good advice, I'll try to hack something together and report back

Comment: using `&shy` has a bunch of bad side-effects and doesn't work exactly the way I hoped. I tried replacing every single character with character + &shy; but then it behaves just like word-break:break-all; Aswell when trying to copy the text you get all the bunch of &shy; copied with aswell... Any other ideas? :\

Comment: Also note that `word-break` is inherited, so it should be fine for the OP to continue to put it on the parent element and let the child inherit it. (Just pointing this out in case there is some constraint that prevents you from applying it to the child.)